# Flask WTF FieldList - Cannot access form data on submit

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms, fieldlist

I have a form to edit a 1:many set of data. I am using FieldList for the rows of related records. The form displays correctly (it's not pretty yet), and I can edit. On submit, I can access the parent record form.name.data but I cannot figure out how to access the child data in form.dqs (the fieldlist) to save them back to the db.

In validate_on_submit, I can see the form.name.data but not the data in form.dqs (the fieldlist).

I've tried everything... I looked through all the objects in the debugger and cannot see the actual data anywhere.

This is my first form like this.. I'm trying to stay in the Flask/WTF universe, but open to the best solution for any of what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

```
class DemoReport(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'demoreports'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    org_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    demotypes = db.relationship('DemoType', backref='demoreport', lazy='dynamic') #  many:1 Demoreport:demotype
    demorptqs = db.relationship('DemoRptQ', backref='demoreport', lazy='dynamic') #  1:many Demoreport:demorptq

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<DemoReport %r>' % self.id

class DemoRptQ(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'demorptqs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    org_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    # many DemoRptQ's: 1 demoreport
    demoreport_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('demoreports.id'))
    # many demoreptQs: 1 question
    question_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('questions.id'))
    qorder = db.Column(db.Integer)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<DemoRptQ %r>' % self.id
```

```
class DemoRptQForm(Form):
    qorder = IntegerField('Order')

class DemoReportForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Demo Report Name', validators=[Length(0, 80), DataRequired()])
    dqs = FieldList(FormField(DemoRptQForm), min_entries=10)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

```
@main.route('/demoreport/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_demoreport(id):
    if id==0:
        demoreport = DemoReport()
        demoreport.org_id = current_user.org_id
    else:
        demoreport = DemoReport.query.get_or_404(id)
        if demoreport.org_id != current_user.org_id:
            flash('That Demo Report is not in your Org.')
            return redirect(url_for('.demoreports_list'))

    demorptqs = DemoRptQ.query.filter_by(demoreport_id=demoreport.id).order_by(DemoRptQ.qorder).all()

    form = DemoReportForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        demoreport.name = form.name.data
        for dq in form.dqs:
            db.session.add(dq)
        db.session.add(demoreport)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('.demoreports_list'))
    form.name.data = demoreport.name
    form.dqs = demorptqs
    return render_template('demoreport.html', form=form, demoreport=demoreport, demorptqs=demorptqs)
```

```
<form action method="post" class="form" role="form">
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.name, class='form-control', placeholder='Demo Template Name') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-default" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    {% for dq in form.dqs %}
        <div class="row">
            <input class="form-control" style="width: 10%" id="dq.qorder" name="dq.qorder" placeholder="Order" type="text" value="{{ dq.qorder }}">
            <div class="col-md-2>">{{ dq.question.qbody }}</div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>

</div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Cant you simply access form data in ```form.fieldname.data```? Take a look at this tutorial, <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/>

Comment: I did that, but the exact syntax I could not figure... see my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using this specific syntax:

demorptqs[i].qorder = form.dqs.entries[i]['qorder'].data

Could not get at the data any other way.